# Excel Template Copy and dynamic naming

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which acts as a master. I want to be able to run a macro that will create a copy of the worksheet and rename it, it should be called CQ X where X represents the next number - so CQ5, CQ6 etc. I can obviously copy the worksheet and rename it quite easily but i don't know how best to work out the next number and then add that in?

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many sheet.names have "CQ" and then copy and name the copied sheet tp the next numbers

```
Sub CountAndCopy()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, iCnt As Long, x

    Set WS = Worksheets("Template")

    For Each sh In Sheets
        If InStr(1, sh.Name, "CQ", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then iCnt = iCnt + 1
    Next sh

    x = CStr(iCnt)

    WS.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "CQ " & x + 1
    WS.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @PJCAN1-you need to check this off as the answer